# Wrong AST selection

Tags: antlr, antlr3

Given the following ANTLR v3 grammar:

```
tokens
{
   OPTION;
   UNKNOWN;
}

statement : my_statement
          | UNKNOWN_KEYWORD -> ^(UNKNOWN)
          ;

my_statement : FIRST SECOND type = THIRD? -> ^(OPTION $type?);


FIRST : 'my';

SECOND : 'keyword';

THIRD: 'best';

UNKNOWN_KEYWORD : .;
```

Why is that when the string "my keyword this_is_garbage" is parsed, it is picked-up by *my_statement* while it should have been picked-up by *UNKNOWN_KEYWORD* (i.e. the AST that is returned is *^(OPTION $type?)* while it should have been *^(UNKNOWN)*)?

Comment: `THIRD` is optional in your parser rule, so the rule matched `my keyword` just fine, and didn't even advance to `this_is_garbage`.

Comment: Yes, it will not match my_keyword but it does not return the AST ^(UNKNOWN), which is what one would expect.How can the grammar be fixed so that it returns this AST?

Comment: The behavior you're seeing is exactly what I'd expect from this grammar :) Well, assuming that `UNKNOWN_KEYWORD` is defined somewhere (`UNKNOWN` is a single character). `my_statement` matches so the second branch of `statement` isn't even tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input `my keyword this_is_garbage` will be tokenized as  follows (assuming spaces are hidden):

```
FIRST              'my'
SECOND             'keyword'
UNKNOWN_KEYWORD    't'
UNKNOWN_KEYWORD    'h'
...
UNKNOWN_KEYWORD    'e'
```

I.e., a `FIRST` token, a `SECOND` token and then 15 `UNKNOWN_KEYWORD` tokens.

If you now try to match `statement`, the rule `my_statement` would gladly consume the `FIRST` and `SECOND` tokens, leaving the 15 `UNKNOWN_KEYWORD` tokens in the token stream.

However, if you would repeatedly match your `statement` rule like this:

```
parse
 : statement+ EOF
 ;
```

then you'd end up with the following parse tree:

[image]

or this AST:

[image]

And if you want to group all `UNKNOWN_KEYWORD` tokens into 1 alternative, you'll need to do:

```
statement : my_statement
          | UNKNOWN_KEYWORD+ -> ^(UNKNOWN)
          ;
```

Note that you **cannot** group `UNKNOWN_KEYWORD` inside your lexer:

```
UNKNOWN_KEYWORD : .+ ;
```

because that would cause the lexer to gobble up the entire character stream into 1 single `UNKNOWN_KEYWORD` token.

Comment: You should also add here that UNKNOWN_KEYWORD should be a .* loop, not only a single char, to match the intended behavior.

Comment: Yeah, but you probably mean `+`.

Comment: True, a plus is correct. But your addition about that loop is not :-) UNKNOWN_KEYWORD would only eat everything if there was no other rule matching before it. It's perfectly fine to have a catch-all rule at the end of a grammar.

Comment: @MikeLischke, no, I said that you cannot have a lexer rule that has only `.+`, I didn't say you can't have a lexer rule that matches a single char using (a single) `.`